# dropdown li in codeigniter not fetching proper values from database using id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a site with a dropdown menu that shows city names and after clicking a particular city it redirects to another page that shows the city details.

My problem is that in this page the menu is showing only the current single city, but should show all of them.

[image]
here is the image showing header:

after clicking particular city this is how header is looking:

[image]
Header view code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <?php foreach ($race_details as $city) {?>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'id') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url('city/'. $city->id); ?>">
                <?= $city->location ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Controller code:

```
public function city() {
    $data['site'] = $this->Site_model->get_site_details();
    $data['page_title'] = $data['site']->site_title;
    $city_id = $this->uri->segment(2);

    if($city_id){
        $data['race_details'] = $this->Site_model->get_race_details_by_city($city_id);
        $this->load->view('city_page', $data);
    }
}
```

Modal code:

```
public function get_race_details_by_city($city_id='') { 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $city_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('race_details');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Can you print $data['race_details'] and check how many data you got from query result?

Comment: are you using city id from the URL after redirecting to specific city page? if yes then it will result only one city.

Comment: @RajdipChauhan Thank you for replying! Getting single record

Comment: @VinayPatil Thank you replaying !! yes i'm using id. but in header it is showing only one city

Comment: @Prajakta to fetch cities in header you are using `get_race_details_by_city` and passing `city_id` from the URL, right? if yes then `get_race_details_by_city` will return the only single city.

Comment: @Prajakta: It's showing only one city means you pass city_id in your url so it's match with database and its give you only single record as output. You need to create separate function for get all the cities.

Comment: @VinayPatil I agree with you!

Comment: @RajdipChauhan ok then how do i get id in url if not using the same function. i'm passing city id to get particular city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need dropdown of all the cities (Home page, Header page) you can use all_cities_list() function, Now whenever you need race details by city you can call get_race_details_by_city() function by passing city id in it so both will work for you

```
public function all_cities_list() { 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('cities');
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_race_details_by_city($city_id='') { 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $city_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('race_details');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! i figured out solution i dont know it is the right way or not. I used different header for city page and different header for other pages.

Comment: I already had two different functions but could not get any idea how to use them!! Anyways your answer helped me!!

Comment: is there any other way without using different header

Answer (score 0):

Using two header for city options it's not valid solution. You can also use below alternate solutions.
Always use all_cities_list() function for get list of all the cities list on all the pages.

Now whenever you click on city page get that city_id and pass it in controllers like

```
public function city() {
    $data['site'] = $this->Site_model->get_site_details();
    $data['page_title'] = $data['site']->site_title;
    $data['city_id'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->load->view('city_page', $data);
}
```

Now you can match your city_id in foreach loop data on header page

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <?php foreach ($race_details as $city) {?>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item <?= ($this->uri->segment(2) == 'id') ? 'active' : ''; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url('city/'. $city->id); ?>" <?= if(isset($city_id)) { if($city->id == $city_id){echo 'selected';}} ?>>
                <?= $city->location ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you Rajdip!! I will use this solution.